# TypeError: can't concat int to bytes

Tags: python, imaplib

Running this code in order to read email message:

```
if uid > uid_max:
            result, data = server.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)')  # fetch entire message
            msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
```

I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: can't concat int to bytes`

How to fix this?

Comment: What's the value of result and data? Can you paste the entire stack trace?

Comment: @Jtcruthers https://gist.github.com/CapitolDev/29f945be0f484c10c79e32a5e36f8341

Comment: as mentioned in the [link](https://gist.github.com/nickoala/569a9d191d088d82a5ef5c03c0690a02#gistcomment-2565159) (but since deleted) you provided, the code is not compatible with python 3.x

Comment: If you're using Python3.x, message_from_bytes() is generally a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by replacing **uid** with **str(uid)**

```
result, data = server.uid('fetch', str(uid), '(RFC822)')
```

bye bye